# Why does pip prevent install of potentially insecure and unverifiable files?

Tags: python, pip

I tried to install pybgpdump using pip but pip threw the error below.

```
pip install pybgpdump
Downloading/unpacking pybgpdump
  You are installing a potentially insecure and unverifiable file. Future versions of pip will default to disallowing insecure files.
  Error <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed> while getting https://jon.oberheide.org/pybgpdump/downloads/pybgpdump-0.2.tar.gz (from https://jon.oberheide.org/pybgpdump/)
Cleaning up..
```

Why does pip try to verify the pybgpdump package?

What is the difference between a secure and insecure file?

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because from pip version 1.3, https is the default protocol.

In [CHANGES.txt](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/develop/CHANGES.txt):

```
**1.3 (2013-03-07)**

* SSL Cert Verification; Make https the default for PyPI access.
  Thanks James Cleveland, Giovanni Bajo, Marcus Smith and many others (:pull:`791`, CVE-2013-1629).
```

and because [pybgpdump](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pybgpdump/0.1) is hosted on an external server (https://jon.oberheide.org/pybgpdump/) and you don't have the right certificate installed.

Note also that the pypi package index hold only the version 0.1 of pybgpdump and the last version is 0.2